# how can I solve the "ptrace error" in 32-bit machine of Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Make file errors -

```
    make[2]: *** [arch/x86/kernel/ptrace.o] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [arch/x86/kernel] Error 2
    make: *** [arch/x86] Error 2
```

After I extract my linux-2.6.32.tar.bz2 and implement new system call and then type "make" at that time i can get the above errors .

Comment: That's not the real error message.  That's Make simply saying that there was an earlier error in the (C compilation) command that was supposed to generate `ptrace.o`.  Solve >>that<< problem.

Comment: But after this making is just stopped and i am not get any files

Comment: Try with make  2> log.txt and log.txt will have detailed information about errors.

Answer (score 2):

```
https://lkml.org/lkml/2012/8/9/281

Above link i found in google. This link helps me to solve the problem.

--- linux-2.6.32.59/arch/x86/include/asm/ptrace.h
+++ fix_ptrace.o_compile_error/arch/x86/include/asm/ptrace.h
@@ -130,6 +130,7 @@

 #ifdef __KERNEL__

 #include <linux/init.h>
+#include <linux/linkage.h>

 struct cpuinfo_x86;
 struct task_struct;
@@ -142,8 +143,8 @@
             int error_code, int si_code);
 void signal_fault(struct pt_regs *regs, void __user *frame, char *where);

-extern long syscall_trace_enter(struct pt_regs *);
-extern void syscall_trace_leave(struct pt_regs *);
+extern asmregparm long syscall_trace_enter(struct pt_regs *);
+extern asmregparm void syscall_trace_leave(struct pt_regs *);
```